# difference between loop iterations in python and Java or C

Tags: java, python

I am learning python and seeing the difference in this loop conditions declarations I just have a question that how exactly the for loop in python is different from same algorithm `for loop`in C or Java, I know the difference in syntax but is there difference in the machine execution, and which is faster
for example

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if i in range(3,7):
        print i
```

and in java

```
for(int i=0,i<10;i++){
    if i>=3 && i<7
        system.out.println(i);
```

Here I just want to know about the difference in actual iterations over `'i'` not the printing statements or the output of the code.
Also comment on the `if` condition used to check whether `'i'` is in between 3 and 7. in python if I had used the similar statement `if i>=3 and i <7:` what difference would have it made.

I am using python2.7

Comment: Python2.x or Python3.x?

Comment: I think a bounds check is actually faster than seeing if it is in a range? Someone correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You could easily time this by yourself. It would be interesting.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn then both should result in the same performance i mean the bounds vs range.

Comment: When posting code here, please try to make sure it's *valid* code. If you're posting pseudo-code, then state so.

Comment: @dreamer I tested it, and I was wrong: bounds checks are O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using python 2.x, then the `range` call creates a full-fledged `list` in memory, holding all the numbers in the range. This would be like populating a `LinkedList` with the numbers in Java, and iterating over it.

If you want to avoid the list, there's `xrange`. It returns an `iterable` object that does not create the temporary list, and is equivalent to the Java code you posted.

Note that the `in` condition is not equivalent to a manual bounds check. Python will iterate through the range in O(n) looking for the item.

In python 3.x, `xrange` is no more, and `range` returns an `iterable`.

Comment: I tested range(5,10) and xrange(5,10) in python and understood what you meant. damm i have been using range only all this time

Comment: It's not really a problem for small ranges :)

Comment: Yes but I have been using python for a MOCC on Discrete Optimization and for assignments we have to solve problems like knapsack in python where the test cases includes data up 10000s nodes.   Also i stopped using `in` where I dont really have to